# Problems with tidyverse after installing glue

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am having a problem loading `tidyverse` after installing glue.

I have the following error after `library(tidyverse)`

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘glue’

Some things I have tried:

1. `remove.packages("glue")`
2. `remove.packages("tidyverse")`
3. `install.packages("tidyverse")`
4. restart R session

## Edit

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] odbc_1.1.4       cellranger_1.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.15       pillar_1.1.0       compiler_3.4.3     plyr_1.8.4         bindr_0.1         
 [6] tools_3.4.3        digest_0.6.12      bit_1.1-12         memoise_1.1.0      tibble_1.4.1      
[11] gtable_0.2.0       rlang_0.1.6.9003   DBI_0.7            yaml_2.1.14        bindrcpp_0.2      
[16] gridExtra_2.3      withr_2.0.0        knitr_1.19         hms_0.3            devtools_1.13.3   
[21] stats4_3.4.3       bit64_0.9-7        grid_3.4.3         inline_0.3.14      R6_2.2.2          
[26] rstan_2.17.3       ggplot2_2.2.1      blob_1.1.0         scales_0.5.0       StanHeaders_2.17.2
[31] assertthat_0.2.0   colorspace_1.3-2   lazyeval_0.2.1     munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: Use `sessionInfo()` to tell is which versions of these packages you are using. Specifically i'd be interested in the version of `tidyverse`, `glue` and `dplyr`. Seems like you might have updated dplyr further than the tidyverse version or something.

Comment: (Side laugh: I've never used or even looked for `remove.packages` ... I've just been deleting the underlying directory, which works fine because R does not maintain any sort of registry.)

Comment: have you tried installing glue only?

Comment: @ColinFAY I honestly don't really need `glue` I am fine without it, but I would like `tidyverse` back. It think it is odd that they are somehow connected in the error.

Comment: `dplyr` depends on `glue`, so you won't be able to load it unless `glue` is well installed. Hence my question.

Comment: @ColinFAY I see. I just tried `install.packages("glue")`
`library(glue)`. no luck. My problems started after `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/glue")`

Comment: I just fixed it. Looks like I had to do an uninstall of `glue` then `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/glue")` again. Kind of an odd problem :/ Thanks for the tip on `glue` being the problem @ColinFAY

Comment: Cheers ! 
I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it, and maybe that will help others in the near future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr` depends on glue, and it seems it is not well installed (if at all) on your machine.

If `glue` is installed, you should consider first uninstalling it.

Then, try reinstalling the glue package with : `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/glue")`